# How to perform data synchronization in mongo db

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I need help here. I am creating an endpoint which is supposed to be consumed on a monthly payment subscription. I don't want anyone to hit
the API if he has not paid for a given month for example this sept 2021 anyone who has not paid should get message eg 'Kindly pay your monthly subscription'.
I have created a table 'payment_table'  to store monthly payment of everyone consuming API with field like month , year and payment_date.

I am creating a monthly subscription service that is for one to use my api he has to pay on a monthly basis.

I have two tables;
Table one >>to store payment by each client which has that is
month

1. month
2. Year
3. client_id

Year
Table Two >> to store client details and has;

1. client current_float
2. client_id
3. Client Name

table two can be updated from 2 channels one Web or service(our local payment service called mpesa)

so upon amount entering in table 2 I need to subtract amount and push it in table 2

so the service that consume my api is app. I need when end month reaches the app can read client table and if there is enough funds
it auto push to table one to indicate as paid for that one.

Remember as the app read from table one and push payment to table 2 the client can be doing deposit on the other end.

Here is demo code.

```
@Service
public class PaymentHandlerService{

@Autowired
PayRepo payRepo;

public void doDeposit(long payment_id,double amount_to_deposit)//one user depositing from same payment id
{

   Payment p=payRepo.findById(payment_id);
   p.setCurrent_float(p.getCurrent_float()+amount_to_deposit);
   payRepo.save(p);
   

}
 public void withdraw(long payment_id,double amount_to_withdraw)//one user withdrawing from same payment id
     {
         Payment p=payRepo.findById(payment_id);
         p.setCurrent_float(p.getCurrent_float()-amount_to_withdraw);
         payRepo.save(p);
     } 

}
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
class Payment{
double current_float=200;
long id;
}
```

My main concern or question is how can I achieve this without calling payment_table each and every request to check if one hitting the API has paid the monthly subscription.

I am using mongodb and springboot 2.4.3

Comment: I believe what you want is to execute some logic and if requested is satisfying the condition the toy want top proceed else reject, is that correct? If yes, you have two options 1. AOP 2. Filters

Comment: On other end, synchronization can be achieved in multiple ways. Please refer to some java concurrency classes for your reference. I don't think synchronization is needed in your case

Comment: @AmitMishra  I want to ensure that during top up of a client account value should should not be messed up in a case where the same client is being deducted funds by android app.

Comment: Yeah, in that case you cal use concept of locking table row or column where you can perform only 1 transaction at a time.

Comment: @AmitMishra how can I achieve this? this what am looking for